# Jolt convert keys and values as separate set of arrays

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a nested JSON which looks like below. The keys and values from an object needs to be separated into 2 sets of arrays, like shown in expected output.

Input:

```
{
  
  "ms": [
    {
      "ts": "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z",
      "ls": {
        "nr1:name1": {
          "UE": 0.1,
          "LE": 3,
          "TG": 5,
          "UW": null,
          "LW": null
        }
      },
      "ss": {
        "nr1:name1": [
          5.3
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ts": "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z",      
      "ls": {
        "nr2:name2": {
          "UE": 0.1,
          "LE": 0,
          "TG": 0,
          "UW": null,
          "LW": null
        }
      },
      "ss": {
        "nr2:name2": [
          0.03
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Current output is

```
{
  "ts" : [ "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z", "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z" ],
  "nrs" : [ "nr1", "nr2" ],
  "names" : [ "name1", "name2" ],
  "paramnames" : [ "UE", "LE", "TG", "UW", "LW", "UE", "LE", "TG", "UW", "LW" ],
  "values" : [ 0.1, 3, 5, null, null, 0.1, 0, 0, null, null ],
  "act" : [ 5.3, 0.03 ]
}
```

Expected output is

```
{
  "ts": [ "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z", "2024-02-13T12:43:00.000Z" ],
  "nrs" : [ "nr1", "nr2" ],
  "names" : [ "name1", "name2" ],
  "paramnames": {
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW"
    ],
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW"
    ]
  },
  "values": {
    [
      0.1,
      3,
      5,
      null,
      null
    ],
    [
      0.1,
      0,
      0,
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
    "act": [ 5.3, 0.03 ]
  }
```

My JOLT spec looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ms": {
        "*": {
          "ts": "ts",
          "ls": {
            "@0": {
              "*:*": {
                "$(0,1)": "nrs",
                "$(0,2)": "names",
                "*": {
                  "$": "paramnames",
                  "@": "values"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ss": {
            "*:*": {
              "*": "act"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The paramnames and values need to be categorized into sub arrays based on each element in ms array, which I have not been able to do. Can anyone help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add `[&4]` in order to use the indexes of the outermost array which is stated 4 levels up within the tree's level. Besides, the node which starts with `"@0"` is redundant. So, you can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ms": {
        "*": {
          "ts": "&",
          "ls": {
            // "@0": {
            "*:*": {
              "$(0,1)": "nrs",
              "$(0,2)": "names",
              "*": {
                "$": "paramnames[&4]",
                "@": "values[&4]"
              }
            }
            // }
          },
          "ss": {
            "*:*": {
              "*": "act"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : You can use the following one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ms": {
        "*": {
          "ts": "&",
          "ls": {
            "*:*": {
              "$(0,1)": "nrs",
              "$(0,2)": "names",
              "*": {
                "$": "paramnames[&4]",
                "@": "values[&4]"
              }
            }
          },
          "ss": {
            "*:*": {
              "*": {
                "#act": "paramnames[&4]",
                "@": "values[&4]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to get the following output :

```json
{
  <the same as the previous one>,
  "paramnames": [
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW",
      "act"
    ],
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW",
      "act"
    ]
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      0.1,
      3,
      5,
      null,
      null,
      5.3
    ],
    [
      0.1,
      0,
      0,
      null,
      null,
      0.03
    ]
  ]
}
```

as commented.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, is it possible to add "act": [ 5.3, 0.03 ] into the paramnames and values arrays, so that the output arrays looks like  "paramnames": {
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW",
   "act"
    ],
    [
      "UE",
      "LE",
      "TG",
      "UW",
      "LW",
   "act"
    ]
  }
  
  and
  
   "values": {
    [
      0.1,
      3,
      5,
      null,
      null,
   5.3
    ],
    [
      0.1,
      0,
      0,
      null,
      null,
   0.03
    ]
  }

Comment: Hi @VKB , edited to include this new case, take care.

Comment: Thank you again! It saved me a plenty of time.